# $\int _2^3\:\frac{x^2-2x-3}{x+1}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

After I get form of

$\int \frac{x^2}{x+1}dx-\int \frac{2x}{x+1}dx-\int \frac{3}{x+1}dx$

then get

$\left(x+1\right)^2-2\left(x+1\right)+ln\left|x+1\right|-2\left(x+1-ln\left|x+1\right|\right)-3ln\left|x+1\right|$

(problem here i think ^)

using limits; I get b-a

I'm getting $-2$

though the answer is supposed to be $-\frac{1}{2}$

is something wrong with the equation above?

Comment: (1) How did you get that expression for the antiderivative?  (2) If you want to evaluate the integral the easy way, factor the numerator and simplify the rational expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$x^2-2x-3=(x+1)(x-3)$, so you can simplify the integrand.

Comment: @haqnatural: Oh! Yes.Thanks for pointing  it. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int _{ 2 }^{ 3 } \: \frac { x^{ 2 }-2x-3 }{ x+1 } dx=\int _{ 2 }^{ 3 } \: \frac { \left( x-3 \right) \left( x+1 \right)  }{ x+1 } dx=\int _{ 2 }^{ 3 } \: \left( x-3 \right) dx={ \left( \frac { { x }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } -3x \right)  }_{ 2 }^{ 3 }=-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $$

Comment: ok you can factor these  $\frac{\left(x-3\right)\left(x+1\right)}{x+1}$  and let say not these ? for example  $\frac{\left(x-3\right)\left(x-1\right)}{x-1}$

Comment: im confused what types you can factor when doing definite integral

Comment: to tell the truth i didn't understant your comment,can you clearify your point?

Comment: sorry about that ; pretty much am I able to factor and simplify any factorable ration-able expression? because I remember my professor saying that there are some that you can't factor where you could have factored only in algebraic terms such as here.

Comment: @TemurBakhriddinov,it is ok.This is  another question.In your case, we can factor numerator

Comment: You can simplify in this case because $(x+1) = 0 \iff x=-1$, but that does not worry us here because we are integrating from $x=2$ to $x=3$, and on that interval, $(x+1)$ is never equal to 0.

Comment: @amWhy while that's true, it doesn't really address the OP's concern. It should be noted that it wouldn't matter if the integration went across that point....  The Riemann Integral (which I assume the OP is using) can handle a finite number of discontinuities